# Why is the first case "to reducing" and the second one "to reduce"? Is it correct?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Why is the first case **to reducing** and the second one **to reduce**? Is it correct?

> During this time, she studied an environmental management system with an innovative approach **to reducing** pollution in an industrial company. This strategy was successful and allowed the company **to reduce** considerably the level of heavy metals in the wastewater produced.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["approach to address" or "approach to addressing"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70401/approach-to-address-or-approach-to-addressing) It would be valid to use ***to reduce*** instead of ***to reducing*** in the first case of your example, but the second one has to be kept the way it is.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I was thinking like this: _During this time, she studied an environmental management system with an innovative approach for reducing pollution in an industrial company. This strategy was successful and allowed the company to reduce considerably the level of heavy metals in the wastewater produced._ Is it correct?

Comment: Idiomatically it's more common to say *an innovative approach **to** reducing pollution*, but ***for*** is at least "acceptable". That's a separate issue from the choice between "preposition + gerund" *(an approach **to reducing** pollution)* and the infinitive verb version *(she studied... [**in order**] **to reduce** pollution)*.

Answer (score 2):

*To* serves two functions - relation-expressor (like prepositons normally do) and infinitive marker (really more like articles).

> an innovative approach to reducing pollution ...

*To* is used to express a relation between the noun "approach" and "reducing pollution..." - that relation is "directing efforts toward X, X being a goal or desired result".

Objects of prepositions like other objects have to be a noun role - gerunds do that.

> allowed the company to reduce

*To* here is just an infinitive marker.  *To reduce* more or less "hangs" off of the verb "allowed" as something like an indirect object (*to reduce* answers "what?" for the verb "allowed"), though I'm sure it's precise grammatical function is something much more complicated and involves the word "complement".

Answer (score 0):

> with an innovative approach to reducing

In this case the preposition "to" belongs to the noun "approach"

"reducing" is a gerund and acts like a noun.

**Example with a noun**

When filming lions, the photographer times his **approach to** the cubs with great care.

---

> allowed the company to reduce

In this case "to" is part of the verb "reduce" and makes it infinitive.